# Reactjs Warning: input is a void element tag and must not have `children` or use `props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Can anybody tell me why this warning props in console?

```
React.createElement(
  'div',
   { className: 'form-group has-feedback' },
   React.createElement('label', { htmlFor:"lastname", className:"font-14"}, "Last Name"),
   React.createElement(
     "input", 
     { 
     id:"lastname", type: 'text', 
     className: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Last Name', 
     onChange: this.handleChange.bind(this, 'lname') 
     }
   )
)
```

Comment: my input doesnt have any children

Answer (score 40):

I had the same error with  tag below worked for me;

Make the input tags as self closing.

instead of

```
<input> </input>
```

use self closing tag.

```
<input />
```

Comment: I'd also want to add that if you're creating a checkbox/radio form, you should use `<input ... /> Option #1` instead of `<input ...>Option #1</input>`

Answer (score 0):

I removed the `otherProps` in the code below and solved the problem. But I don't know the exactly reason that causing the problem.

```
return _react2.default.createElement('img', _extends({ title: '\u4FEE\u6539' }, otherProps, { src: './imgs/icon/updateicon.png', onClick: this.props.onClick, style: { cursor: "pointer" } }))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this issue, you can always put the element within the render().
Like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<div className= 'form-group has-feedback'>
        <label htmlFor = "lastname" className = "font-14"></label>
        <input id = "lastname" type =  'text', 
        className = 'form-control' placeholder = 'Last Name'
        onChange = 'function()' />
        </div>, 
document.getElementById("options"));
```

Note : Be sure to create an element with id "options" in your index.HTML file.