# Having img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a React.js project but it gives me img is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` error. Here is my code:

```
     <a>
        <img src="/images/2.svg" alt="logo" />
      </a>
     <RightMenu>
        <CustomMenu onClick={()=> setBurgerStatus(true)}/>
      </RightMenu>
      <BurgerNav show={burgerStatus}>
        <CloseWrapper>
          <CustomClose onClick={()=> setBurgerStatus(false)}/>
        </CloseWrapper>
        <li><a href='#'>Vizyon</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Vizyon</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Misyon</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Neden Biz?</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Ekibimiz</a></li>
        <li><a href='./Contact.js'>İletişim</a></li>
      </BurgerNav>
```

I've tried to reinstall node-modules but nothing changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs Warning: input is a void element tag and must not have \`children\` or use \`props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML\`. Check the render method of null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182100/reactjs-warning-input-is-a-void-element-tag-and-must-not-have-children-or-use)

Comment: nope its something different

Comment: Does the error disappear when you remove your `<img src="/images/2.svg" alt="logo" />`? This is just so you would be sure that's the cause of it.